# Can retransmit be used as a noun?

Tags: nouns

Example usage:

> There have been three retransmits.

Is there a more appropriate word?

Comment: [Retransmission](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/retransmit?q=retransmit)

Comment: @MattЭллен *retransmit* and *retransmissions* are entire different things in that part of the universe (comms jargon).

Comment: @Kris how so? perhaps you can make the question better?

Comment: "Neighbor Down: Too many retransmits"; "If no response is received after several retransmits to..."; "Requesting a retransmit from sender: UIP stack can request a retransmit from the application logic"; "...even slightly corrupted data can be processed without having to request a retransmit that delays every subsequent datagram"

Comment: @Kris, would *retransmittals*, used as a noun (which it can be), be acceptable in comms jargon?

Comment: @JLG Tried to differentiate *transmit* used as noun, see answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. *Retransmit* is indeed used as a noun. Significantly, the usage is generally to distinguish from the corresponding 'dictionary' noun *retransmission*.

A given message subjected to retransmission constitutes an entity called a 'retransmit' or an event of 'retransmit':

> "Neighbor Down: Too many retransmits"; "If no response is received after several retransmits to..."; "Requesting a retransmit from sender: UIP stack can request a retransmit from the application logic"; "...even slightly corrupted data can be processed without having to request a retransmit that delays every subsequent datagram"; "The sending system A on the one hand recognizes an error of the transmission on too many retransmits."
>   [from sources]

*If you fail at first, attempt a **retransmit** before raising a ticket*
*Optimize the message before attempting **retransmission**, instead of second and third **retransmit***

Answer (score 1):

When you retransmit something, you retransmitted a retransmission.
So the correct phrasing would be:

"There have been three *retransmissions*"

Comment: *retransmits* and *retransmissions* are entirely different things in that part of the universe (comms jargon).

Comment: I don't see anything related to communications jargon in his question. If he wants an answer on jargon he needs to tag the question with [Jargon](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jargon)

Comment: You meant to say, "When you retransmit something, you **made** a retransmission."

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=%22three+retransmits%22